# (google-chrome:23461): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:34:29.640: cannot open display:

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, ssh, ubuntu-18.04, vnc

I configured VNC on a Ubuntu 18.04 server on AWS ec2 instance following the article at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04

After installing chrome, I tried to open it from the terminal, but unable to open.
I am able to open the browser from the VNC client but opening it from the terminal gives the error 
`(google-chrome:23461): Gtk-WARNING **: 12:34:29.640: cannot open display:`

Anyone who has setup chrome on a VNC server, please help me out.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help iwth software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se] or [su] instead of here.

Comment: check this Q&A : [How do I fix a "cannot open display" error when opening an X program after ssh'ing with X11 forwarding enabled? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi)

Answer (score 1):

You can start it with

```
sudo google-chrome --no-sandbox
```

i did pretty much the same thing you did today, still experimenting